# Online Accounts issue

Tags: gnome, online-accounts, 23.10

I have just installed Ubuntu 23.10 on a new laptop (using X11 because Wayland causes me lots of issues), and I am having an issue with Online Accounts.

I have three Google accounts, all with 2FA set, and two of them were added easily. The third accepts my username and password, then sits there forever failing to load the 2FA popup screen.

I understand that this 2FA screen is displayed using Webkit, so I cleared the cache in both Chrome and Firefox and then tried again - no different.

Can anyone suggest where there might be a temporary file, or a cache or whatever that is causing this issue on just one account?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't solved the issue - more worked around it. I turned off 2FA on the account, then I was able to add it to Gnome. Then turned 2FA back on again. Sorry it isn't a solution!